# Unknown filesystem grub error after unistalling Ubuntu partition from Windows 8

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grubrescue

I have a really big problem.
I deleted Ubuntu partitions from Windows 8 and now on startup of my other pc (im using my old one now to contact you) it shows this error:

Unknown filesystem:
grub rescue>

tried some commands from other threads but it shows me again the same error.
I think that Ubuntu has been completely uninstalled, but this grub rescue pops me out.

I cannot boot in my pc anywhere! either in Windows. The only thing i can do is write commands in grub rescue, or enter BIOS Windows Menu... :(

Comment: I think [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-reinstall-windows) may have some answers for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct procedure. It's for Windows 7 but works for 8 too.
From [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-reinstall-windows)

To remove Ubuntu, you will need a Windows Recovery CD or Installation CD, or a Ubuntu Live CD.

**Note:**  If you don't have a Windows Installation or Recovery CD available, you can download the Windows 7 ISO file (contact Digital River costumer support as [said in Microsoft help page](http://drh.img.digitalriver.com/store/mswpus/ContentTheme/pbPage.Upgrade)).  You cannot install Windows with a genuine Purchased Product Key though, as these ISO files are 100% legal and will only install as an Evaluation copy for 30 days without a product key.

To remove GRUB:

1. Grab a Windows recovery media or installation CD and boot from it.  You should see this on a **recovery media** CD.

   [image]

   And you should see this on an **installation media** CD.  Click "Repair your computer" and you should see a screen like the first image.
   [image: Image from bleepingcomputer.com]
2. Open the Command Prompt, then type `bootrec /fixmbr` into the Command Prompt.

   [image]
3. Reboot and boot into Windows.  Then follow the steps below to remove the Ubuntu partitions.

   (Images from [HowtoGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com))

---

If you don't have a Windows recovery CD or you are too lazy to download and burn the ISO files mentioned before, you can use [Boot-repair](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/).  It is a tool that fixes most boot problems(Windows or Ubuntu).  I suggest using a Windows CD if possible.

To use boot repair:

1. Boot from a Ubuntu live CD or USB
2. Type these lines in the terminal one line at a time.

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install boot-repair
   ```
3. Search for Boot-Repair in the Dash and launch it.

   [image]

   To fix your computer with Boot-repair, simply click the "Recommended Repair" button.  Then follow the steps below to remove the Ubuntu Partitions.

---

To delete the Ubuntu Partitions:

4. Go to Start, right click Computer, then select Manage.  Then select Disk Management from the sidebar.

   [image]
5. Right-click your Ubuntu partitions and select "Delete". **Check before you delete!**
6. Then, right-click the partition that is on the Left of the free space.  Select "Extend Volume".  Go through the Wizard and Finish it.
   [image]
7. Done!